# Checking MomentJS data toString not evaluating properly in if check

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to create a function to create an array of the next two weeks of days that are not Friday, Saturday, or Sunday. `moment().isoWeekday().toString()` returns a number 1-7 depending on the day. I have an if statement checking to see if each day matches 5, 6, or 7, but they all return true no matter the day. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please advise.

```js
    for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
      if (moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString() !== '5' || 
          moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString() !== '6' ||
          moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString() !== '7') {
            console.log(moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString())
            dayArray.push(moment().add(i, 'days').toString());
      }
    }
```

Comment: A few pointers. Why convert the result of `.isoWeekday()` to a string? If you left it as an integer your if statement would be `if (moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday() <  5)` so you would not have to worry about `||` vs `&&` or the like. Also why recalculate `moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday()` 5 times? This just screams "make a variable"

Comment: @gforce301 great point! I just refactored and looks a lot cleaner based on your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to come from you condition, you use OR (||) instead AND (&&)

```
for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    if (moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString() !== '5' &&
        moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString() !== '6' &&
        moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString() !== '7') {
        console.log(moment().add(i, 'days').isoWeekday().toString())
        dayArray.push(moment().add(i, 'days').toString());
    }
}
```